# PocoDynamo not saving child objects with proper Alias or DynamoDbProperty naming

Tags: c#, servicestack, .net-6.0, pocodynamo

I am working with `PocoDynamo` and I am having an issue where the child object properties are not being saved with the proper alias attribute name.

```
public class Doc
{
    [Alias("id")] 
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    [References(typeof(User))]
    [Alias("userId")] 
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Alias("specialty")] 
    public string Specialty { get; set; }
}

public class Practice
{
    public Practice()
    {
        Docs = new List<Doc>();            
    }

    [Alias("id")] 
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    [Reference]
    [Alias("docs")]
    public List<Doc> Docs { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in the image, the parent `Practice` property `docs` is named correctly. However, the child properties of `docs` are pascal cased.

[image]

I tried using the `DynamoDbProperty` attribute but ran into the same issue.

When getting a `Practice` by Id the `docs` collection is loaded, but the properties are null or default values. It seems when reading child objects the Alias / `DynamoDbProperty` attributes are honored. It doesn't work when saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added support for this feature in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/53cb475833304b6ca75beb56cfb08c57af15b9b6).

This change is available from v6.1.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).